# How to upload video to YouTube using C#(WPF) by Google account login, so that every one can use my App

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I tired a simple with client_secret.json, and it can work fine. 
but question is I don't need to login with google account anymore, 
how can I do if I want to upload a video to YouTube using other people's account?

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                //new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer(),
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,

        });/*youtubeService.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);*/

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = "look the video111.";
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
        var filePath = @"C:\Users\plu\Videos\Captures\simple.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "user",
```

User denoted the name of the user who you are logging in as.  Filedatastore will store the user in %appdata% on your machine.  If you want to login as a different user just change "user" to a different string denoting a new user.  To switch back to the original user just change it back to "user"

you can read more about file data store in my article [here](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

Comment: Of course, but where should I click to accept the answer?

Comment: Got it, Thanks again.